# How to popup a dialog when a checkbox is unchecked on webform?

Tags: 6, webforms, javascript

I have a checkbox in Webform. By default, the checkbox is selected. I'd like to popup a message dialogbox if the user uncheck the checkbox. How can that be done in Webform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#checkbox-id').click(function(){
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('You unchecked the checkbox');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please how do I adapt this to open up an off-canvas dialog instead? Drupal.dialog().show() shows a normal dialog and Drupal.offCanvas{} is undocumented? Any pointers please?